# TypeError: props.names.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning to use MUI for the first time, and I'm having trouble making components reusable.
I have this selecter component copy pasted from the website, except I don't want to use their const names = [] array, I want to pass my own array.

SelectSensor.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

// const names = [
//   'Oliver Hansen',
//   'Van Henry',
//   'April Tucker',
//   'Ralph Hubbard',
//   'Omar Alexander',
//   'Carlos Abbott',
//   'Miriam Wagner',
//   'Bradley Wilkerson',
//   'Virginia Andrews',
//   'Kelly Snyder',
// ];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}

export default function SelectSensor(props) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setPersonName(
      // On autofill we get a stringified value.
      typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value,
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">Sensor</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
          id="demo-multiple-name"
          //multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Sensor" />}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >

          {props.names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={name}
              value={name}
              style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
            >
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I changed the function to take props as a parameter because I want to pass a prop and use props.name.map to display the name in the selector.

I call the function in this page:
Query.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import SelectSensor from '../components/SelectSensor';


const Query = () => { 
    const [sensors, setSensors] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchSensors = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('/api/sensorsRoute/names')
            const sensorsArray = await response.text()

            if (response.ok){
                setSensors(sensorsArray) 
            }
        }
        fetchSensors()
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className="query">
            <SelectSensor names={sensors}/>

        </div>
    ) 
} 

export default Query
```

Note that sensors returns an array just like the one MUI used, but with my own strings. I get the error TypeError: props.names.map is not a function. Does anyone know why?

I don't know if the syntax of the code is wrong, or anything like that. It seems like a pretty simple modification that I can't get to work.

Comment: If `props.names.map` is not a function then `props.names` is not an array.  When the error occurs, what is the value of `props.names`?  How does that value differ from what you expect?

Comment: If i directly send {sensors} onto the webpage it displays an array of strings, so I'm confused why it's not an array.

Comment: Put `console.log(props.names);` in the `SelectSensor` component and observe the last logged value to the console before the error occurs.  What is that value?

Comment: response.json() instead of response.text()

Comment: @Berk Kurkcuoglu Oh that was in fact the issue. Thank you!